# Which Stack Exchange site is best for Archimate questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which Stack Exchange site is best to ask questions about [Archimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArchiMate)?

This is a modelling language (like UML) about all aspects of [Process Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_architecture), often at an enterprise level, including business processes, application and technology.

- Stack Overflow comes up when googling Stack Exchange and Archimate, also it has an [archimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/archimate) tag. Archimate questions here are not redirected. However archimate is a lot more general than just software development.
- [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) lists architecture as part of Software Engineering, this seems to fit many questions about Archimate. However Archimate is only mentioned [once](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=archimate) in the whole site.
- Perhaps there is Stack Exchange site I don't know that is more suited to general architecture (not just software)?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean software architecture rather than the design of physical buildings?

Comment: @Catija Indeed not design of phyisical buildings (will update the question), couldn't find the term but wikipedia calls it process architecture (of which software architecture is part, but it is broader than that).

Comment: I would certainly expect some aspects of it to be on-topic on Software Engineering but it might be too abstract to fit in the system development lifecycle. After all, system development is only a small corner of the enterprisy level process architecture takes place.